# Respond to a Restful call

Tags: java, rest, servlets, grails

I am making a restful call to the servlet doGet() method from my grails code.The doGet() method is called successfully and i am able to see the print statements. Once the doGet() is called i need to send a response back to the restful call that the method has been invoked. How to set the response in the servlet so that it can be sent back to the grails

```
    def getStatus(String tableName) {
            try {
                def result
                def resultList = []
                println "attempting to send START signal to http://localhost:9081/ServletSample/ServletSample"
                result = rest.get("http://localhost:9081/ServletSample/ServletSample?tableName="+tableName)
                println "length "+result.length()
                println result.body
                resultList.add(result)
                log.debug "$result.body"
                resultList.each {
                    println "$it.body"
                    if (it.status == 200) {
                        if (it.body == "Starting")

 {
                        println ("starting up")
```

in the servlet i am trying to set the response as

```
response.setContentLength(5);
        response.setStatus(200);
```

but it is not getting received. I am getting the following exception

```
Exception occured in rest service() groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.plugins.rest.client.RestResponse.length() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), each(groovy.lang.Closure), with(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), getXml(), every() from class java.net.URL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert java object into json string and write it into HttpServletResponse. Here is code:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
// Get the printwriter object from response to write the required json object to the output stream      
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String json = new Gson().toJson(someObject);

out.write(json);
```

To convert java object into json string I used [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

But you can manually create json string if it is easy

Comment: what value should be given in the someObject. my grils code is lookin if the status is 200 and body has values "starting"

Comment: Json formatted string like `{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }`. This will be server's response to restful call.

Comment: i got what you mare saying but my question how to parse and get the value for "name" in the grails code so that i will be able to check if the returned value are equal or not